# JavaScript search string

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have this search bar for users to search anything from my database. Here's an example:
"Red Bicycle"
If users type "red bicycle", no matter lowercase or uppercase, it will return result.
However, I want if users search "Bicycle Red" it will also display a result. How can I solve this issue using JavaScript?

Comment: search for the separate words - like `results.filter(result => search.toLowerCase().split(' ').every(word => result.toLowerCase().split(' ').includes(word))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following code:

```
data= "red bicycle";
data=data.split(" ");
search="bicycle red";
search=search.split(" ");
result=data.filter(item=>search.find(sitem=>sitem==item)!=item).length==0?true:false
```

Comment: should I write this in the <script> tag?

Comment: you should write this in onChange handling script of search input field